# Remove Version info from install4j installer

Tags: install4j

I am trying to remove all references to the version in the installer.

Steps I've taken so far:

1. General Settings "Version" field is set to nothing
2. Installer section "File Version" field is set to nothing.
3. Register Add/Remove Program "Item Name" field does not contain version info.

I am building the installer using maven and I am not explicitly passing version information.

However, I am still seeing the Version info in Add/Remove programs under the Version column.
The version is also displayed at the top left of each installer screen: "Installer - NAME VERSION"

Is there a way to completely remove reference to version when building with maven?

Side note: When I was building with ant I did not have this issue.

Thanks,
Bella

Answer (score 0):

> General Settings "Version" field is set to nothing

The project would not compile from the IDE if the version field is empty.

If you want to change the messages that show the version, you can do that by overriding these messages. Go to General Settings->Languages and set up a custom localization file. In the built-in editor click on the "Override message" tool bar button.

For the window title of the installer, override "SetupWindowTitle", for the uninstaller "UninstallAppFullTitle".

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The problem I am having is with: "SetupWindowTitle=Setup - {0}"                                          The {0} consists of 2 variables.  The product name (which I want to keep) and the version which I want to remove.  How do I set {0} to only resolve to the product name?

Comment: You can replace `{0}` with `${compiler:sys.fullName}`